# How many users can edit the same list together?

Tags: list, list-view-threshold, co-authoring

We are using SharePoint 2013 on-premise. We are planning to collect all staffs' (over 5000) information using a list. The list contains several columns with first column is the staff ID. All the staff have contribute permission to the list and they are supposed to edit his/her row and fill in information.

My question is, how many users can edit the same list together? If all of them are editing DIFFERENT rows, is it suppose no error will be threw? If some users encountered error duing save, he/she can just wait for a minute and save again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assumind that you are reffering to user own information by "rows".

As long as you dont have users that are editing the same row at the same time that in doesnt matter.

Your performance will be a bit degraded depending on how your physical architecture is set up but other than that you shouldnt get any errors.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be any errors but it will give you a message saying save conflicts do you want to update the changes  and when you click yes then the user getting this message will see the updated list item that he was working on  and the other user will see the updated list item that he was working on.

As the simultaneous save is practically not fully possible. But after some time both the users can see all the changes with the updated list items.

This wont give you error unless same list item is updated at the same time.